# ¿Para qué sirve la restricción 'New' en métodos genericos C#?

Tags: c#

He visto métodos con unas restricciones en donde dice que el parametro `T` va a ser de tipo `Icomparable` seguido de otro argumento que es el `new()` el cual no tengo idea de cuál es su función.

```
public class ItemFactory2<T>
    where T : IComparable, new() { }
```

Comment: @Flxtr no, en este caso es una restricción que indica que el tipo `T` debe heredar de `IComparable`. No es que `T` va a heredar de `Icomparable`, sino que debe hacerlo.Y como indican en una respuesta,`new()` es una restricción que indica que `T` debe tener un constructor público sin parámetros

Comment: @Pikoh toda la razón en tu comentario ;)

Answer (score 8):

`New()` denota que `T` debe ser un tipo de dato de referencia con un constructor público sin parametros.

En tu ejemplo `T` debe derivar de la interfaz pero también debe ser un tipo de dato de referencia.

Te dejo un [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) a la documentación,  en la que podrás ver los diferentes tipos de restricción que se pueden aplicar.

Comment: Para completar la respuesta, que es correcta, yo añadiría un enlace a la documentación. [Aqui la tienes](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

Comment: Listo, inserte el enlace a la documentación para que se puedan ver los diferentes tipos de restricción que se pueden aplicar!

Answer (score -2):

Sirve para crear tipos anonimos. Los tipos anonimos, sirven para crear propiedades customizados en un objeto, sin crearte ninguna clase.

```
var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };  

Console.WriteLine(v.Amount + v.Message);
```

[Tipos anonimos en .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

Comment: No. Estas equivocado, lo que pregunta el OP tiene que ver con generics,  no con tipos anónimos. Mira la respuesta de @BrianJerez